# Receiving video stream on Android from GStreamer through RTP

Tags: android, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtp

I want to create an **Android application** that **receives a video stream** from **GStreamer** through **RTP** with a **low latency**, like a security camera app. I am a beginner on GStreamer and Android. The video is encoded with **h264**.

For that, I have several ideas :

- use ExoPlayer2, but I am not sure if it's possible to add specific options to be compatible with the gstreamer stream.
- use GStreamer for Android, but it's not beginner-friendly.

I tried to read the video stream and it's successful with VLC on Windows with a sdp file like this :

```
v=0
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

But the latency is high because of buffer.

It's successful with GStreamer thanks to this command line : `.\gst-launch-1.0.exe -v udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp,clock-rate=(int)90000,payload=(int)96" !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=true`

And on Android with QGroundControl (using GStreamer), however the latency is high.

I followed tutorials to read video with ExoPlayer2 but I didn't manage to read video stream.

I tried to follow the GStreamer Android tutorial however I have the impression that the tutorial is outdated and only allows to display a video and not a video stream (please tell me if I'm wrong).

I am confused, all the results of my research are old (more than 5 years) and I think that the technologies to realize my application have evolved (at least I hope so).

Please, help me to find a way to follow.

Best regards.

Comment: I fail to understand what your actual question is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @FlorianZwoch ! I want to find a way to receive RTP video stream on Android. 

A brief summary of my situation : I have a server that uses Gstreamer to manage the video stream, this server sends me the stream thanks to RTP and I want to receive this stream in my Android application.

And my question is : is there a maintained technology / framework that makes it possible to receive and view a video stream without being too complex? Because I've trouble using Gstreamer for Android.


I hope I've been clearer.

Comment: It sounds like you have it running but are not satisfied with the latency. Low latency is something you will never get out of the box. It depends on specific tuned encoder and decoder. It is a specific scenario and a huge, complex topic.

Comment: Not exactly, I managed to retrieve it with applications (VLC, QGroundControl) but not with mine (which I created by following the Gstreamer Android tutorial). For now, I just want to display the video stream, regardless of latency.

Comment: The gst-parse launch line should be transferable to Android. May require another video sink, not sure. You should be able to follow basic GStreamer examples, specifically `gst_parse_launch()` api function will translate that launch line into a pipeline you can then play.

Comment: The pipeline conversion is a fuzzy step for me, but I will follow your advice and search in this area. Thanks for your help !